# I want pre-selected option in the update form already

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-template

I am using array of mat-select to display array of object contains some set like:

```
typesOfAccess = [{1 : 'View Image'},{2 : 'Tag MPxN'},
{3 : 'Configure User'},{4 : 'Assign UserGroup'},
{5:.......},{6:..........}]
```

I am subscribing data from API who having numbers saved in array with their string value.
like below:

```
this.UserEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      is2FAEnabled:[''],
      AccessRights : ['',Validators.required]
    });
```

I want to display number of  the array which i get from api to be pre-selected in HTML.

```
<mat-selection-list formControlName="AccessRights" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)" required>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of typesOfAccess; let i = index" [value]="i+1" [selected]="AccessRights.option">
      {{tta[i+1]}}
   </mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

Please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the selection property binding and just update the form control value this will reflect to the html element

```
<mat-selection-list formControlName="AccessRights" >
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of typesOfAccess; let i = index" [value]="i+1">
      {{tta[i+1]}}
     </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

set the `AccessRights` value when create the form group

```
this.UserEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      is2FAEnabled:[''],
      AccessRights : ['2',Validators.required]
    });
```

or set the value manually like this

```
this.UserEditForm.get('AccessRights').setValue('2'); // will select Tag MPxN
```

**Updated**

you need to send an array base of the selected items like [1,3]

```
this.UserEditForm.get('AccessRights').setValue([1,3]); //
```

if you want to select a single value justlike this

```
this.UserEditForm.get('AccessRights').setValue([3]); //
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assguq)

Comment: i want to dynamically fetch the value from HTTP calls. Can not set values manually.

Comment: can you share with us an example of how you get the valus by http calles ? 

Comment: this.UserEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({ name: ['', [Validators.required], email : ['',Validators.required], mobile : ['', [Validators.required] is2FAEnabled:[''], AccessRights : [this.AccessRights,Validators.required] }); this.apiService.getUserById(+userId) .subscribe( data => { console.log(data); this.UserEditForm.patchValue(data); }); }

Comment: not sure. thats what i want to know. I want to select options dynamically if i sent array of id.

Comment: @sagar03 I have update the answer and include a live demo , hope this will help 

Comment: @sagar03 happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-generating-form-controls):

> The value for each control name is an array containing the initial value as the first item in the array.

The initial value in your component is `''`. Change it to whatever you want the initial value to be:

```
AccessRights : [initialValue ,Validators.required]
```

Comment: this.UserEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   
      name: ['', [Validators.required],
      email : ['',Validators.required],
      mobile : ['', [Validators.required]
      is2FAEnabled:[''],
      AccessRights : [this.AccessRights,Validators.required]
    });
    this.apiService.getUserById(+userId)
      .subscribe( data => {
           console.log(data);
          this.UserEditForm.patchValue(data);
      });
      
  }

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors in the above code. Try this:  
  
```this.UserEditForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      name: ['', [Validators.required]], 
      email : ['',[Validators.required]], 
      mobile : ['', [Validators.required]],
      is2FAEnabled: [''],
      AccessRights: [this.AccessRights, [Validators.required]]
    });```  

  
What is the output of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: it selecting all the options available.

Comment: Hi @JohanSwanepoel you are correct   but I think is the only problem is  the value need to ba an array ,I have create an example base of the anwer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assguq  